# UI Layout for messaging app xml android programatically

Tags: java, android, html, css, xml

I want to display the following data as displayed in a messaging app.
In HTML you do like.....

```
<li> 
<img style="display:inline-block;">
<div style="display:inline-block;vertical-align:top;">
<span style="display:block;">Daniel Bryan</span>
<span style="display:block;">@ricking2</span>
</div>
</li>
```

What is the possible alternative in android by **programatically** in **.java** not direct in **.xml** ??

**JSONArray**

```
[  
    {  
        "name":"Daniel Bryan",
        "img":"pictures\/smallest\/dierdrepic.jpg",
        "username":"ricking2"
    },
    {  
        "name":"HackerManiac HillClown",
        "img":"pictures\/smallest\/belitapic.jpg",
        "username":"ricking06"
    }
]
```

**.JAVA** (heres what i tried to do but things are not as expected)

```
final LinearLayout rl = (LinearLayout) main.findViewById(R.id.mainL);
for (int i = 0; i < json.length(); i++) { 
    try {
        JSONObject c = json.getJSONObject(i);
        LinearLayout LL = new LinearLayout(main);
        ImageView pp = new ImageView(main);
        TextView name = new TextView(main);
        TextView username = new TextView(main);
        int generatedId = generateViewId();
        pp.setId(generatedId);
        LL.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
        new ImageLoadTask(pp).execute("http://110.224.222.126/"+c.getString("img"));
        name.setText(c.getString("name") + " \n");
        name.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
        username.setText("@"+c.getString("username")+" \n");
        LL.addView(pp);
        LL.addView(name);
        LL.addView(username);
        rl.addView(LL);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

}

Comment: Any particular reason you don't want to just inflate an xml layout for this?

Comment: whats inflating  ? @MikeM if its easier and get what i want then sure i will use it

Comment: You would design your layout xml for an individual message item, then use a LayoutInflater to inflate a new row from the xml for each item. It's a rather broad topic, but there are [plenty of examples](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bandroid%5D+inflate+layout) on the site. Additionally, it looks like you're pretty much just recreating a ListView, which you might want to investigate as well.